# Cosuming a java webservice json into Angular4

Tags: java, angular, web-services

I made a java webservice with Jersey and Javax.ws.rs, and at my controller a made a method that returns a list of json objects. This is the method >

```
@Path("chamados")
public class ChamadoController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/")
    public List<Chamado> listChamados(){
        Chamado c1 = new Chamado();
        c1.setId(50);
        c1.setAssunto("assunto1");
        c1.setMensagem("oi");
        c1.setStatus(Status.NOVO);

        Chamado c2 = new Chamado();
        c2.setId(20);
        c2.setAssunto("assunto2");
        c2.setMensagem("oi2");
        c2.setStatus(Status.FECHADO);

        List<Chamado> list1 = new ArrayList<Chamado>();
        list1.add(c1);
        list1.add(c2);

        return list1;
    }
}
```

The output when I run the project with apache and access /rest/chamados/ is this >

```
[{"id":50,"assunto":"assunto1","mensagem":"oi","status":"NOVO"},
 {"id":20,"assunto":"assunto2","mensagem":"oi2","status":"FECHADO"}]
```

My issue is when i try to print it at my angular4 project, i never done this before so im kinda lost, this how im tryng to print it >

```
 export class AppComponent{
     data: any = {};
     constructor(private http: Http){
         this.getData();
         this.getImages();
     }


     getData(){
         return this.http.get(this.apiURI).map((res: Response) => res.json())
     }

     getImages(){
         this.getData().subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data);
     })
  }

    private apiURI = 'http://localhost:8080/aprendendo-java-backend/rest/chamados/';             
}
```

This is the error I get when trying to console.log >

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/aprendendo-java-backend/rest/chamados/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Any tips on whats wrong or how should I be doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

look at this documentation: [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Add an annotation `@CrossOrigin` to your java method like this:

```
@Path("chamados")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
public class ChamadoController {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/")
    public List<Chamado> listChamados(){
        Chamado c1 = new Chamado();
        c1.setId(50);
        c1.setAssunto("assunto1");
        c1.setMensagem("oi");
        c1.setStatus(Status.NOVO);

        Chamado c2 = new Chamado();
        c2.setId(20);
        c2.setAssunto("assunto2");
        c2.setMensagem("oi2");
        c2.setStatus(Status.FECHADO);

        List<Chamado> list1 = new ArrayList<Chamado>();
        list1.add(c1);
        list1.add(c2);

        return list1;
    }
}
```

Change the port number (9000 port in my example) to what ever port you use in your Nodejs server or what ever web server port you have that serves your web pages.

Comment: Thanks for that link seems good, ill try making a new project from scracth using Spring, i cant just @CrossOrigin on my controller, it gives me the error "cannot find symbol", i tried adding  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.airhacks</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxrs-cors</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2</version>
        </dependency>        but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome try installing this "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin" extension.
[enter link description here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi)

Try maybe help.

This extension causes it to fool your webservice, not reading the request as a request from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

you can also use JsonP, you need to wrap the JSON in a function and then use the Jsonp facility in Angular.

https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp

Answer (score 0):

Same issue i had faced. i was changed `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")` into `@CrossOrigin` then its working

Comment: CrossOrigin is not recognized in my code, maybe differente jax-rs version?  Mine is this one   >                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    <dependency><groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the awnsers guys, i was able to do it by adding this to the end of getMethod >>

```
        return Response
        .status(200)
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD")
        .header("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600")
        .entity(list1)
        .build();
```

Not sure if this is safe tho....anyone know?